# Preventing New Windows from Capturing Focus wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython, focus

How do I make a newly created window in wxPython not take focus? I'd like to be able to create a new window, without focus jumping to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never tried it, but I've [heard](http://www.michaelfogleman.com/2009/01/wxpython-show-without-focu/) you can do

```
window.Disable()
window.Show()
window.Enable()
```

Answer (score 1):

That seems a little counter-intuitive. However, you can also simulate this by creating and showing the second frame and then calling Raise() on the original frame.